# how to get an automatic name tag for persistent volume when it is bound to an EKS pod

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, persistent-volumes, amazon-ebs, kube-prometheus-stack

I have an existing prometheus-stack running with dynamic pv allocated. it has got the ebs volume with name tag as "kubernetes-dynamic-pv-23234324" in the aws ui under volumes, but when i did the same changes of adding volumeclaim with same storage class, the pv got allocated, but the ebs volume did not get any name tag. it was empty. what could be the reason and where should i fix this. Prometheus is setup using kube-prometheus-stack

Below is the one which has the name tag created automatically

```
Name:              pvc-baa0b631-8919-474d-b8b3-fc9212345cb6
Labels:            topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                   topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1a
Annotations:       kubernetes.io/createdby: aws-ebs-dynamic-provisioner
                   pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                   pv.kubernetes.io/migrated-to: ebs.csi.aws.com
                   pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   aws://us-east-1a/vol-0e6dce28sdf072159
```

Below one got an empty tag for the name

```
Name:              pvc-a1c54d37-f238-400f-8aee-7c593932babb
Labels:            topology.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                   topology.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1a
Annotations:       pv.kubernetes.io/migrated-to: ebs.csi.aws.com
                   pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-name: 
                   volume.kubernetes.io/provisioner-deletion-secret-namespace: 
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection external-attacher/ebs-csi-aws-com]
StorageClass:      gp2
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   vol-0c95c41abskjsd4a3d
```